# Segmentation fault while searching in 2D matrix?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am making a algorithm to find a number in a 2D matrix where every row is sorted and the first element of every row is greater than the last element of the previous row.

I though of making a index translation function which translate the 2D indexing into 1D indexing and helping in to pipe it in a binary search.

This worked well until we enter a matrix of 1xn or nx1 where n is a natural number, the algorithm goes nuts and returns a segmentation fault.

PS. it is leetcode problem of finding element in 2D matrix.

The code is like

```
class Solution {
public:
    int rows = 0;
    bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {
        rows = matrix.size();
        return binarySearch(matrix, 0, matrix.size() * matrix[0].size() - 1, target);
    }
private:
    pair<int, int> iT(int index) { // index translation
        cout << '[' << index/rows << ',' << index%rows << ']' << endl;
        return {index/rows, index%rows};
    }
    
    bool binarySearch(vector<vector<int>> & matrix, int l, int r, int x)
    {
        if (r >= l) {
            int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
            if ( matrix[iT(mid).first][iT(mid).second] == x)
                return true;
            if ( matrix[iT(mid).first][iT(mid).second] > x)
                return binarySearch(matrix, l, mid - 1, x);
            
            return binarySearch(matrix, mid + 1, r, x);
        }
        return false;
    }
    
};
```

someone might complain about the iT function, please let it be as it is.

EDIT: the binary searching is having *l* as left index and *r* as right index and the *mid* is the middle index. *x* is the target value.
example case.
Input: matrix = [[1,3,5,7],[10,11,16,20],[23,30,34,60]], target = 3
Output: true

it failed for matrix=[[1,1]] and target=2. the standard out put is [0,0] [1,0] . as you can see it does have a segmentation fault, [1,0] is not in matrix, but why the recursive call goes in that line. IDK

Comment: your usage of indices is very unintuitive and looks rather complicated. It might need some explanation to be understandable. And please post a [mcve]. The code you posted alone can impossibly cause a segfault. You need to create an instance of `Solution` and call the methods

Comment: Perhaps you have too deep recursion? And is the matrix sorted appropriately?

Comment: I think I now understand your index transformations. Though, there are many ways the code can go wrong. Please include some example input

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the matrix is sorted , it is labeled in the post itself.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the algorithm only fails in condition like 1xn or nx1 type matrix

Comment: This looks like something used to solve a so-called "competition" site problem, does the site give you the input that causes the crash? Then create a proper [mre] locally and hard-code the input to call your functions and use a debugger to catch the crash to see when, where and why it happens.

Comment: "the algorithm only fails in condition like 1xn or nx1 type matrix" then please include such example input. You need to understand that bugs typcially arent found by looking at some piece of code. I used your code and I had to add the missing pieces and add the example input and found that there is no segfault: https://godbolt.org/z/1nxnzhsj4. Please help us to help you and include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude for example , it failed for matrix=[[1,1]] and target=2. the standard out put is [0,0] [1,0] . as you can see it does have a segmentation fault, [1,0] is not in matrix, but why the recursive call goes in that line. IDK

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number example added in comment

Comment: you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69404586/edit) the question to add missing information.

Comment: The shown algorithm works only for completely square matrixes, only NxN matrixes, basically. Pop quiz, what are possible values for `X%n`? It's 0 through `n-1`, of course.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it workes for NxM matrix , i checked my self.

Comment: When you "checked my self", did you check it for matrixes where `M` is 1? Because you wrote, in your own question, that it doesn't. If it worked for any `NxM` matrix, then it should work for an `Nx1` matrix, where `M` is 1. But it doesn't. I can guarantee you that this does not work at all for `NxM` matrixes. It's possible that for a given `NxM` matrix and its specific values this ***might*** give the correct answer, but after putting some other values into the matrix, and trying it, you will always find some particular set of values where this fails completely.

Answer (score 1):

You should divide index by row size (not by number of rows) -- check it by yourself

Then your code will work

Comment: I found the issue, but still thanks.

Comment: the algorithm only fails when the target is not in the matrix and the target is bigger than the greatest element in the given matrix.

Comment: As I said, replacing "row count" with "row size" will solve all your problems. Including the values greater than the maximum and others.
(I just ran your code with this replacement)

It's all about the serialization and deserialization of the matrix...